# Как обновить страницу перед считыванием информации?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

Идет запрос информации с сайта при помощи бота. 3 раза в сутки (строго по часам) идет обновление информации на сайте. Структура сайта:

```
<a href="#" class="newsletter"><img src="" alt="" class="small">
<noindex>
    <span>Новости от 8 часов</span>
</noindex>
</a>
```

В заданные моменты идет считывание информации, но он фиксирует информацию каждое считывание от момента запуска бота, она не меняется, даже если на сайте ее обновят. и в 15ч он пишет ту же информацию, что и в 8 утра. Информация на сайте обновляется ровно в 08:00, далее в 15:00

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

client.on("ready", () => {
   const url = '';

   async function news() {
      const letter = await request(url);
      const $ = cheerio.load(letter);

      cron.schedule('0 5 8 * * *', () => {
         $('.newsletter noindex span')
            .each((index, element) => {
               const exp = $(element).text();
               client.channels.cache.get("").send(exp));
            })
      });
        cron.schedule('0 5 15 * * *', () => {
         $('.newsletter noindex span')
            .each((index, element) => {
               const exp = $(element).text();
               client.channels.cache.get("").send(exp));
            })
      });
   }
   news();
});
```

Как обновлять страницу перед считыванием